# How can I use attribute routing without endpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

How can I use attribute routing in the Home Controller, like

```
[Route("")]
[Route("Home")]
[Route("Home/Index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

to get to the main page and not have

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

in Startup.cs?

Comment: What version mvc are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you use net core your startup could be like this:

```
             app.UseRouting();
            

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you do not use attribute routing, you have to use endpoint. The endpoint is a mapping to the routing template.

When the first HTTP request comes in, the Endpoint Routing middleware will map the request to an Endpoint. It will use the EndpointDataSource created when the App starts, use it to traverse to find all available Endpoints, and check the routing and metadata associated with it in order to find the most matching Endpoint.

Once an Endpoint instance is selected, it will be attached to the requested object so that it can be used by subsequent middleware.

Finally, at the end of the pipeline, when the Endpoint middleware is running, it will execute the request delegation associated with the Endpoint. This request delegate will trigger and instantiate the selected Controller and Action methods, and generate a response. Finally, the response is returned from the middleware pipeline.

Take a look at the following flow chart.

[image]

About attribute routing, it improves the freedom of routing and also provides good support for restful api.